# Php-ml: PHP Machine Learning library, behavior issues

Tags: php, machine-learning, regression, php-ml

I'm using [this](https://php-ml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/machine-learning/regression/svr/) library to predict numbers the thing is that I don't understand or don't get the problem in this piece of code, it always returns the same

```
>>> $SVR = new SVR(Kernel::LINEAR);
=> Phpml\Regression\SVR {#4304}
>>> $SVR->train([[1], [2], [3], [4],[5]],[3,1,2,3,2])
=> null
>>> $SVR->predict([6])
=> "2.1"
>>> $SVR->predict([7])
=> "2.1"
>>> $SVR->predict([8])
=> "2.1"
>>> $SVR->predict([9])
=> "2.1"
```